# JInternal Frame does not pop up

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm working on a mvc project for which I have created a login form for which after logging in should show a JInternal frame which for some reason is not showing up I've tested the connection to the db and is working fine also there is no problem with the validation just the window not showing up.

```
 private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
    User u = new User();
    
        if (!txtUsername.getText().equals("") || txtPassword.getText().equals("")) {
        u.setUsername(txtUsername.getText());
        u.setPassword(txtPassword.getText());
        u.setUserType(cbType.getSelectedItem().toString());
        
            if (userDAO.login(u)) {
            
            String userID =String.valueOf(u.getUserId());
            String username = u.getUsername();
            String userType = u.getUserType();
            
           
            MainPage mainPage = new MainPage(userID, username, userType);
            mainPage.setVisible(true);
            
            }else{
            
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The username or password are incorrect");
            }
        }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The spaces must be filled");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't see `mainPage` been added to a `JDesktopPane` - maybe have closer look at [How to Use Internal Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Comment: I'd also encourage you to make use of debug statements and the debugger to verify that the code execution is going where you think it should be going

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.